# How To search special symbols AWS Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to be able to get search results with special symbols like @.  Every time I try to do this I don't get any hits and when I try without the special symbols everything works fine. Here is the request I'm making.

```
search?q=(or(prefix+field%3Demail+%27email@email%27)(term+field%3Demail+%27email@email%27))&q.parser=structured&return=user
```

Comment: CloudSearch or ElasticSearch service? You tagged the question with very generic tags and didn't specify enough details in the question.

Comment: CloudSearch, sorry.  Updated tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it by replacing @ to a different character.

Comment: can you also tell us which characters are valid to use as a replacer ? In my case, I need to replace @ (at) and - (hyphen)

Comment: Where we need to implement this replacing in Front end or in backend service

Answer (score 1):

The symbols are being removed during text processing as described in [Text Processing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html)

> According to the word break rules, strings separated by whitespace
>   such as spaces and tabs are treated as separate tokens. In many cases,
>   punctuation is dropped and treated as whitespace. For example, strings
>   are split at hyphens (-) and the at symbol (@).

You may be able to solve this with a different [Text Analysis scheme](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the field as literal as literal fields are not tokenized.

Comment: Just make sure you don't need to search this item by the partial terms. 

For example, in the sample movie data, the title field is configured as a text field. If you search the title field for star, you will find all of the movies that contain star anywhere in the title field, such as star, star wars, and a star is born. This differs from searching literal fields, where the field value must be identical to the search string to be considered a match.

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html#searching-text-terms