# How to execute a structured query containing symbols in AWS Cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to execute a structured prefix query in Cloudsearch.

Here's a snippet of the query args (`csattribute`  is of type text)

```
{
    "query": "(prefix field=csattribute '12-3')",
    "queryParser": "structured",
    "size": 5
}
```

My above query will result in `No matches for "(prefix field=csattribute '12-3')"`.

---

However, if I change my query to

```
{
    "query": "(prefix field=csattribute '12')",
    "queryParser": "structured",
    "size": 5
}
```

Then I will get a list of results I expect.

---

I haven't found much in my brief googling.  How do I include the `-` in the query?  Does it need to be escaped?  Are there other characters that need to be escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got pointed to the right direction via this SO question: [How To search special symbols AWS Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298419/how-to-search-special-symbols-aws-search)

Below is a snippet from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html

> Text Processing in Amazon CloudSearch ... During tokenization, the
> stream of text in a field is split into separate tokens on detectable
> boundaries using the word break rules defined in the Unicode Text
> Segmentation algorithm.
>
> According to the word break rules, strings separated by whitespace
> such as spaces and tabs are treated as separate tokens. In many cases,
> punctuation is dropped and treated as whitespace. For example, strings
> are split at hyphens (-) and the at symbol (@). However, periods that
> are not followed by whitespace are considered part of the token.

From what I understand, `text` and `text-array` fields are tokenized based upon the analysis scheme (in my case it's english).  The text was tokenized, and the `-` symbol is a word break token.

This field doesn't need to be tokenized.  Updating the index type to `literal` prevents all tokenization on the field, which allows the query in my question to return the expected results.